# Only part of the legend shows in multiple axes graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on a graph with two y axes and three plots (two plots share same x and y axes. Only two legends show (for Eq 8 and Eq5), not all three for some reason. NB: v, v2 and v3 were previously defined via lengthy calculations
here is my code and the graph:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Percent glycerol in the mixture')
ax.set_ylabel('Eq 4 and Eq 5')
ax.plot(x, y, '-r', label='Eq 4')
ax.plot(x,y2, '-b', label='Eq 5')
ax.grid()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Eq 8')
ax2.plot(x, y3, '-g', label='Eq 8')
ax2.legend(loc=0)
ax3 = ax2
color = 'tab:red'
ax3.errorbar(75, 29.45, 0.2, fmt='o')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph with multiple axes]